# Symfony2: Redirecting from HTTPS-Route to HTTP-Route

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have the base route `"/"` like `http://example.com` and I want to redirect this route to `http` if someone calls `https://example.com`. What I am doing wrong? Do I have to put the redirect option somewhere else? THANKS!

In my routing yml I have:

```
my_website:
    resource: "@MyWebsiteBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    defaults:
        route: home //<-- This is my name of the route "/" in my controller
        permanent: true
```

Comment: This might help http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html  in the end you shouldn't have to handle this in your routes but instead in security.

Answer (score 0):

In your routing.yml:

```
home:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Default:index     }
    host: "www.example.com"
    schemes:  [http] # This is where the magic happens!
```

An alternate solution if you want ALL routes you can go to your security.yml and change the access_control parameter to this :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY], requires_channel: http }
```

If you ever need https to access an admin :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY], requires_channel: http }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN], requires_channel: https }
```

More information can be found here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Comment: In my Controller I already have this:  
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home", schemes= { "http" })
     * @Template("MyWebsiteBundle:Home:index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    { ...

I've already defined a scheme. So I don't need this in my routing.yml?

Comment: Yes, don't quote me on that but I think that even if you're using annotation, this goes in routing.yml. I prefer YAML to annotation so I'm a little less familiar with it. Tell me if that works i'm curious about the outcome.

Comment: Just making a follow up, did you eventually figure out your answer?

Comment: When you tried my answer, did you clear your cache? Because whenever you play in the routing.yml/config.yml it's very important to cache:clear after. If it's in prod it's cache:clear --env=prod

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
my_website:
    resource: "@MyWebsiteBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    requirements:
        _scheme:  http
```